# How can I make a nested for loop to print n, n-1 .... n - (n - 1)?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to make a nested for loop that prints the following:
if n =  5

```
5
5 4
5 4 3
5 4 3 2
5 4 3 2 1
```

Below you can find the code I have been using to try to get this but it is not working:

```
def main():
    n = 5
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, i):
            print(n, end=' ')
            n = n - 1
        print('\n')

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make few changes:

- Store `n` to variable and use it inside inner loop, decrement by one in each iteration.
- Inside loop should run till `i+1`, because the end is exclusive.

---

```
def main():
    n = 5
    for i in range(n):
        n1 = n
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(n1, end=' ')
            n1 -= 1
        print('\n')

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been trying the whole night and the answer was right in front of me :/. I guess it is not that intuitive either I still need more practice.

Answer (score 0):

so code is

```
def main():
    n = 5
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print(n-j, end=' ')
        print('\n')

main()
```